# Office 365 click to run automation

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, office365

I've seen posts from several years ago stating that automation wasn't supported in older click to run installations of Office, eg 2010. Can anyone tell me if this is still the case with Office 365?

For background, the reason I'm asking is I support some .NET desktop applications which use late-binding to automate Excel and Word. They've worked fine for all users until a recent client who has Office 365 Business click to run. On this PC (and this one only, so far) the app fails ("Cannot create ActiveX component") at the line:

```
Dim oExcel as Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

User claims Excel is definitely installed and working (and Registry key at /HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Excel.Application/Curver confirms 2016 is present.) Also `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` executes correctly, so it doesn't seem to be a scripting problem.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Do they have more than one version of Excel installed?

Comment: Perhaps a 32 vs 64 bit problem?

Comment: The applications have been tested and work correctly on various other systems, including another PC owned by the same client with the same 64 bit OS, so I think we can rule out 32 vs 64 bit.

Comment: I believe they upgraded to Office 365 from a different version so it may be an installation issue, but I'm trying to find whether this is definitely supported in 365 click to run before I tell them they need to reinstall Office.

Comment: I've been hit with the same issue today. It was fine until this weekend, after which an update got pushed and all my office files [do not have the office icons anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fbYt.png)